# HTACCESS letter cut off

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been working rigorously on finding the error in my HTACCESS file. I am having a problem with my HTACCESS rewrites. My htaccess file cuts off the first letter of my file   rewrites/php files. Any suggestions of what may be the issue?
    Below is an example of my HTACCESS file. Any suggestions?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "cuts off the first letter"? `index.php` becomes `ndex.php`?

Comment: Yes that happens for every file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything there that's removing a letter

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should create a new file. Might be a system glitch.